# Sending post message to PHP server using java/groovy

Tags: java, php, groovy

Good afternoon everyone.

I'm new in using both java/groovy and PHP and was working on a attempting a basic method to send a json message to the a php file.

I have a php file which is as follows

```
<?php
 
    $query = "Hi, my name is: '".$_POST["name"]."'";
    echo $query;
    
?>
```

and my java/groovy file is as follows

```
post = (new URL("http://localhost/Ping/Post.php")).openConnection()

message =  '{"name":"Max Weiver"}';

println("This is the message = "+message);

post.setRequestMethod("POST");

post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

post.setDoOutput(true);

post.getOutputStream().write((message).getBytes("UTF-8"));

println("This is the detailed message: "+post);

postResponseCode = post.getResponseCode();

println "Response Code: ${postResponseCode}"

postResponseData = post.getInputStream().getText();


println "Response Data: ${postResponseData}"
```

And I just want the groovy console to output something like this

```
Hi, my name is: 'Max Weiver'
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Response Code: 200
Response Data: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Ping\Post.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
Hi, my name is: ''
```

I'm aware that there are solutions to be made within the php file to sort this problem (like using the json_decode and the isset, etc). But I'm wondering whether there modification needed within the groovy/java file to successfully send the POST message without changing the php script?

*Note: As I said earlier, I'm sort of new in both languages so do let me know if I'm missing something obvious :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php `_POST` is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

to make groovy call successful the easiest way to pass parameters in
`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format:

`name1=value1&name2=value2&...`

changed groovy code:

```js
def post = new URL("http://httpbin.org/post").openConnection()
def body =  [name: "Max Weiver"]
//convert map to x-www-form-urlencoded
body = body.collect{k,v-> "$k=${URLEncoder.encode(v,'UTF-8')}" }.join('&')

println("This is the body = "+body);

post.setRequestMethod("POST")
post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
post.setDoOutput(true)
post.getOutputStream().write(body.getBytes("US-ASCII"))

def postResponseCode = post.getResponseCode()
println "Response Code: ${postResponseCode}"

def postResponseData = post.getInputStream().getText()
println "Response Data: ${postResponseData}"
```

Comment: It worked as a charm. Thank you so much :) I'm just wondering if you can explain why you chose "US-ASCII" in the post.getOutputStream().write(body.getBytes("US-ASCII"))?

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode(v,'UTF-8')` used to produce body. url encoder returns string with ascii only characters - any nonascii chars will be converted to something like `%99`. so, when we are converting this string to bytes there is no need to use utf-8 again. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding